# Android XML parsing

Tags: android

I have to parse the url 
http://local.yahooapis.com/LocalSearchService/V3/localSearch?appid=YahooDemo&query=pizza&zip=94306&results=2 and show the result in android simulator

I have done earlier parsing in android
I did not get problem in that 
Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: If you don't have any problem... i don't see your point. What have you done yet ?

Comment: I have done parsing of the url  http://dealsfinger.com/service.asmx/GetAllMall

Comment: whats ur email id ykatchou so that i can tell you all on email,,, I will be very thankful for your help,,,,

Comment: for got sakes use pastebin.com to post code, im flagging this question as it is made of fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic `XML Parsing` tutorial on Android using `SAX API` :

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser/

Comment: You have not specified what error or problem you are getting.